# Port 53, address already in use in MAC

Tags: domain-name-system, port, mac

I'm trying to set up my own DNS server. But I can't start my server as it says port already in use. I read most of the posts regarding this, but didn't work for my mac.

This is the error I'm getting.

> socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use

I tried:

```
lsof -i :53
```

but this shows no process running. I tried to run server with sudo and that didn't work either. Help !

Edit: 
Output of

> sudo lsof -i:53

```
    COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
named   32932 root   21u  IPv6 0xbaf59411fd1ef68f      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
named   32932 root   22u  IPv4 0xbaf5941209b1a30f      0t0  TCP localhost:domain (LISTEN)
named   32932 root   23u  IPv4 0xbaf594121173200f      0t0  TCP 192.168.10.13:domain (LISTEN)
named   32932 root  512u  IPv6 0xbaf59411fc375b8f      0t0  UDP *:domain
named   32932 root  513u  IPv6 0xbaf59411fc375b8f      0t0  UDP *:domain
named   32932 root  514u  IPv6 0xbaf59411fc375b8f      0t0  UDP *:domain
named   32932 root  515u  IPv6 0xbaf59411fc375b8f      0t0  UDP *:domain
named   32932 root  516u  IPv4 0xbaf59411fc376bdf      0t0  UDP localhost:domain
named   32932 root  517u  IPv4 0xbaf59411fc376bdf      0t0  UDP localhost:domain
named   32932 root  518u  IPv4 0xbaf59411fc376bdf      0t0  UDP localhost:domain
named   32932 root  519u  IPv4 0xbaf59411fc376bdf      0t0  UDP localhost:domain
named   32932 root  520u  IPv4 0xbaf5941212699b8f      0t0  UDP 192.168.10.13:domain
named   32932 root  521u  IPv4 0xbaf5941212699b8f      0t0  UDP 192.168.10.13:domain
named   32932 root  522u  IPv4 0xbaf5941212699b8f      0t0  UDP 192.168.10.13:domain
named   32932 root  523u  IPv4 0xbaf5941212699b8f      0t0  UDP 192.168.10.13:domain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try again

```
sudo lsof -i :53
```

and post result please

EDIT:
So, you have `named` service already active.

What dns server are you trying to configure? If different from default `named` (BIND) you can try to disable `named` service, start and enable your dns server and see if everything go fine. If not, you can enable again `named` and configure it to fulfill you necessity

Comment: I have edited the post. Please have a look .

Comment: So, you have named service already active. What dns server are you trying to configure? You can try to disable named service, start and enable you dns server and see if everything go fine. If not, you can enable again named.

Comment: How do I disable named service?

Comment: https://docs.menandmice.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6360966

But it's better you understand what are you doing before messing up with crucial services like dns..